# axios.post("/checkitem/add.do",this.formData).then((res)....gets 404

Tags: java, vue.js

> When I use Dubbo and zookeeper to practice a project, encountering a 404 problem.
> By rights, the "post" address has no problem, and **this.formData** is received.

```
            handleAdd () {
            //进行表单校验
            this.$refs['dataAddForm'].validate((valid) => {
                if(valid){
                    //表单校验通过，发生ajax请求，将录入的数据提交到后台进行处理
                    console.log(this.formData);
                    axios.post("/checkitem/add.do",this.formData).then((res) => {  
                        //关闭新增窗口
                        this.dialogFormVisible = false;
                        if(res.data.flag){//执行成功
                            //新增成功后，重新调用分页查询方法，查询出最新的数据
                            this.findPage();
                            //弹出提示信息
                            this.$message({
                                message:res.data.message,
                                type:'success'
                            });
                        }else{//执行失败
                            //弹出提示
                            this.$message.error(res.data.message);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    //校验不通过
                    this.$message.error("数据校验失败，请检查你的输入信息是否正确！");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        },
```

---

```
package com.itheima.controller;

import com.alibaba.dubbo.config.annotation.Reference;
import com.itheima.constant.MessageConstant;
import com.itheima.entity.Result;
import com.itheima.pojo.CheckItem;
import com.itheima.service.CheckItemService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * 检查项管理
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/checkitem")
public class CheckItemController {
    @Reference//查找服务
    private CheckItemService checkItemService;
    //新增检查项1
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public Result add(@RequestBody CheckItem checkItem) {
        try{
            checkItemService.add(checkItem);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();//服务调用失败
            return new Result(false, MessageConstant.ADD_CHECKITEM_FAIL);
        }

        return new Result(true,MessageConstant.ADD_CHECKITEM_SUCCESS);

    }
}
```

---

```
package com.itheima.service.impl;

import com.alibaba.dubbo.config.annotation.Service;
import com.itheima.dao.CheckItemDao;
import com.itheima.pojo.CheckItem;
import com.itheima.service.CheckItemService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * 检查项服务
 */
@Service(interfaceClass = CheckItemService.class)
@Transactional
public class CheckItemServiceImpl implements CheckItemService {
//    注入dao
    @Autowired
    private CheckItemDao checkItemDao;
    @Override
    public void add(CheckItem checkItem) {
        checkItemDao.add(checkItem);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkLnl.png)
**this is the error message**

In frankly, I don't know if these codes are useful, wishing someone can give me a direction.

oh, I forgot the ".do", the web.xml as follows

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- 指定加载的配置文件 ，通过参数contextConfigLocation加载 -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:springmvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

when I change the post become get

`axios.get("/checkitem/add.do",this.formData).then((res) => {`
Sadly, it can't works.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ua7f.png)

---

I don't know if that can provide some information, when I click the confirm to submit data the 404 only shows in console but the network has no response.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ067.png)

---

> I'm sorry to forget to show the error message and with these probably can find what mistake it is.

```
10:59:48,611 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:312 - Looking up handler method for path /checkitem/add.do
10:59:48,612 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:322 - Did not find handler method for [/checkitem/add.do]
10:59:48,613  WARN PageNotFound:1205 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/checkitem/add.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc'
10:59:48,613 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Never worked with this backend part, but as i see, ur path in axios request is /add.do, but in the controller seems like just /add. Also same issue could be if u doing POST request , but ur Method has GET type, can u please check this.Can u first change axios.post to axios.get and check if it works ;D

Comment: thank you, regarding the..do, I have the web.xml forgot to post. The web.xml as above. But I cant to solve the problem by changing the “post” to "get".

Comment: Sorry didnt work with these things :D Just what i see from error, ur request cant find this path on controller...and i dont have any other suggestion how to solve. Maybe anyway path in ur controller is just "/checkitem/add" so u can just try to delete .do from requst url in axios request and try 1 more time :D Just for me its like shot in the dark.

Comment: I find some error messages could you have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I always try to find errors in the front end result in forgetting to check up idea's message, after noticing that I rapidly resolve this problem. The answer is my springmvc's annotation package is wrong mising the "itheima".

```
    <dubbo:application name="health_backend" />
    <!--指定服务注册中心地址-->
    <dubbo:registry address="zookeeper://127.0.0.1:2181"/>
    <!--批量扫描-->
    <dubbo:annotation package="com.itheima.controller" />
    <!--
        超时全局设置 10分钟
        check=false 不检查服务提供方，开发阶段建议设置为false
        check=true 启动时检查服务提供方，如果服务提供方没有启动则报错
    -->
    <dubbo:consumer timeout="600000" check="false"/>
```